# Get connectionexception when using RestHighLevelClient for Elastic search

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have downloaded the spring boot project that is available in the link [Spring boot elastic search example](https://www.journaldev.com/18148/spring-boot-elasticsearch).

It doesn't seem to be working. I get the below exception when I try to fetch the data. Also, I am unable to connect to the 9200 port, and I do not see anything running on the port to confirm if the data is being added to the repository.

```
java.net.ConnectException
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:168)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:822)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:210)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:155)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried a few other examples as well but when I use RestHighLevelClient I am unable to add and fetch data. I get the exception `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information`  in those cases.

How to get RestHighLevelClient working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify the version of your rest-high-level-client in your pom and compare against the version of ES you are connecting with? As one can expect, the versions have to be compatible. 
Please find snippet of my pom below.

> 

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
    <!-- ES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

A few other tips that might help when troubleshooting:

- verify the log file of your ES and see whether there are any errors when you connect
- use curl to connect to http://localhost:9200
- use the Chrome Elastic Search Head plugin to http://localhost:9200
- verify your firewall

Hope this helps. 
All te best,
Wim

Comment: Unable to connect to  http://localhost:9200, netstat shows there is nothing bound to port 9200. Firewall, not the problem. The exception mentioned above is the error I get when I try to add data. I am assuming the ES instance isn't getting creates.